# Diagnosing xaml stowed_exception 88000FA8: clayoutmanager updatelayout()

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

We have a large UWP app that too frequently lists stowed_exception 88000FA8 in our crash group reporting.  It gives no indication as to which page the exception occurs and it does not appear to relate to our code.  From what I can make out, it appears to be a layout issue, but I have no more to go on than this.

We have tried to throw the exception ourselves in both release and debug on several computers but have not been able to reproduce it. We cannot create a sample app to try and reproduce the crash because we don't know where on our large app it is coming from.

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
CLayoutManager UpdateLayout() layoutmanager.cpp:368
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
CCoreServices NWDrawTree() xcpcore.cpp:6922
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
CCoreServices NWDrawMainTree() xcpcore.cpp:6718
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
CWindowRenderTarget Draw() windowrendertarget.cpp:137
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
CXcpBrowserHost OnTick() winbrowserhost.cpp:538
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
CXcpDispatcher Tick() xcpwindow.cpp:1450
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
CXcpDispatcher OnReentrancyProtectedWindowMessage() xcpwindow.cpp:1048
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
CDeferredInvoke DispatchQueuedMessage() xcpwindow.cpp:293
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
CXcpDispatcher MessageTimerCallbackStatic() xcpwindow.cpp:1527
CoreMessaging.dll
Microsoft__CoreUI__Dispatch__TimeoutHandler$CallbackThunk() common__dllinterop.cpp:505
CoreMessaging.dll
Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch::TimeoutManager Callback_OnDispatch() timeoutmanager.cs:431
CoreMessaging.dll
Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch::EventLoop Callback_RunCoreLoop() eventloop.cs:871
CoreMessaging.dll
Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch::UserAdapter OnUserDispatch() useradapter.cs:700
CoreMessaging.dll
Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch UserAdapter_DoWork() useradaptern.cpp:505
CoreMessaging.dll
Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch UserAdapter_WindowProc() useradaptern.cpp:751
user32.dll
UserCallWinProcCheckWow() clmsg.cxx:279
user32.dll
DispatchMessageWorker() clmsg.cxx:3137
Windows.UI.dll
Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher ProcessMessage() dispatcher.cpp:327
Windows.UI.dll
Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher WaitAndProcessMessagesInternal() dispatcher.cpp:1959
Windows.UI.dll
Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher ProcessEvents() dispatcher.cpp:581
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
CJupiterWindow RunCoreWindowMessageLoop() jupiterwindow.cpp:1244
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
DirectUI::DXamlCore RunMessageLoop() dxamlcore.cpp:2217
twinapi.appcore.dll
Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView Run() coreapplicationview.cpp:1798
twinapi.appcore.dll
_lambda_476a253d60a149be58fa202b506b2c7b_ operator() coreapplicationview.cpp:1212
SHCore.dll
_WrapperThreadProc() thread.cpp:321
kernel32.dll
BaseThreadInitThunk() thread.c:64
ntdll.dll
RtlUserThreadStart() rtlstrt.c:998
```

I'm hoping that someone has come across this and some idea of what could be causing the exception.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose this issue. Have you checked the event view logs?

Comment: Thanks for you comment.  These exceptions show up in our crash group, we have not been able to throw the exception on our own computers.  We do not know the users who are throwing the exceptions so we cannot ask them for their event logs.

Comment: From your exception,we can infer it is caused by the XAML layout,but we need error code and a more detail log.So we recommend you use the following tools to get more detail exception information.1.[UnhandledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception).When you use it,you can see the information locally.2.[Hockeyapp](https://hockeyapp.net/) and [appcenter](https://appcenter.ms/).These require you to integrate it yourself, it will upload the exception information to the website, which can be viewed in its user center.

Answer (score 0):

We believe we may have found the answer to this.  We set the default language to en-US in the application manifest and have not had a crash relating to clayoutmanager for over two weeks.